# can not ping by host name for some computers

Tags: 11.04, hostname, ping

I have 11.04 installed.

It is joined to a domain. I am able to ping some of my computers by their name, but some I can't.
Those I can't are our NAS machines (Readynas Netgear). I can ping them only by IP from my Ubuntu machine. But I can ping them regularly by host name, from any other windows machine.

Please advise what should I check?

Comment: Ok, solved it, just added: WINS to the /etc/nsswitch file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `WINS` to the `hosts:` line in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat lsass
group:          compat lsass
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] wins dns mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
```

This tells the system to use WINS in order to lookup netbios. The `winbind` package has to be installed for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

For a more hackish method then the one listed by [@Saariko](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57154/can-not-ping-by-host-name-for-some-computers/57295#57295) you could edit your hosts file. This is not a robust solution and has to be updated manually, if your network set up changes.

It can also hide network problems if names don't resolve correctly through other tools like wins and dns

Host file on Ubuntu and many other *nix is found

> /etc/hosts

In windows the hosts file is usually found

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
>   %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

To make changes in Ubuntu edit the file and put in the ip address and hostnames you want.

> sudo vi /etc/hosts
>   192.168.1.1  servername
>   192.168.1.2  server2name

In my host file I add all the web severs I set up for my web development

> 127.0.0.1 local.home
>   127.0.0.1 local.site1

Then I can ping

```
$ ping local.home
PING local.home (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
```