# Can't ping Windows hostname

Tags: networking, samba, ping, hostname

I can neither ping nor access Windows 7 Samba shares through the hostname.

As recommended at (inter alia) [can not ping by host name for some computers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57154/can-not-ping-by-host-name-for-some-computers), I have edited 
`/etc/nsswitch.conf` 
to include

`hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] wins dns mdns4`

I have also restarted services as suggested, yet no go.

When attempting to ping my Windows 7 machine, the output is:

`ping: <hostname>: Name or service not known`

Advice as to how best to resolve Windows hostnames on Ubuntu will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The hostname must be found in some DNS you are accessing. Is this the case here? For Ubuntu, the simplest hostname registration is through the /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a firewall problem.

Solution as suggested at https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/11/prevent-linux-firewalls-interfering-with-samba-commands-in-a-home-network-that-uses-broadcast-netbios-name-resolution/

1. `iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j CT --helper netbios-ns`
2. Add the following lines to the end of the file `/etc/ufw/before.rules`

```
    # The following is needed to enable Samba commands to
    # work properly for broadcast NetBIOS name resolution
    #
    # raw table rules
    *raw
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    -F OUTPUT
    -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j CT --helper netbios-ns
    COMMIT
```

3. Restart UFW!